# How does keras basic optimizer works?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, keras-2

Here is part of `get_updates` code from `SGD` from `keras`([source](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L165))

```
moments = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]
self.weights = [self.iterations] + moments
for p, g, m in zip(params, grads, moments):
    v = self.momentum * m - lr * g  # velocity
    self.updates.append(K.update(m, v))
```

## Observation:

Since `moments` variable is a list of zeros tensors. Each `m` in the `for loop` is a zero tensor with the shape of `p`. Then the `self.momentum * m`, at the first line of the loop, is just a scalar multiply by zero tensor which result a zero tensor.

### Question

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - during a first iteration of this loop `m` is equal to 0. But then it's updated by a current `v` value in this line:

```
self.updates.append(K.update(m, v))
```

So in next iteration you'll have:

```
v = self.momentum * old_velocity - lr * g  # velocity
```

where `old_velocity` is a previous value of `v`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When `Keras` training function is running. It actually calls to each `symbolic compiled` function from `self.updates` array. As each element in this function  is symbolic, it allows to keep the old values of the calculation as well. i.e: `moments` array is actually been declared only once. the `K.update(m,v)` contains the full symbolic information about `v`. Did I get it right?

Comment: I think - yes - you've got it.